# SQL Estado por usuario en el mes

Tags: sql

Buen día. Por favor su ayuda, tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL donde registra si un usuario estuvo operativo o no durante el mes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deseamos tener una categorización o al final tener un campo de estado donde se compare el registro con el mes anterior. Algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hemos hecho algo con la Union de 3 consultas pero quisiéramos tener todo en una sola porque actualmente la consulta es muy lenta.

Tengo algo así pero creo que no es muy práctico:

```
SELECT 
max(CONVERT (date, ('01/' + cast (mes as varchar)+ '/' + CAST (anio as varchar)), 103)) as fecha, 
usuario, 
'Retiro' as estado 
FROM operaciones 
group by usuario 

union all 

SELECT 
min(CONVERT (date, ('01/' + cast (mes as varchar)+ '/' + CAST (anio as varchar)), 103)) as fecha, 
Usuario, 
'ingreso' as estado 
FROM operaciones 
group by usuario 
order by 2 

Revisando la base de datos esta montada sobre server 2008
```

Comment: Podrías dejar el select que tienes actualmente y lo que has intentado.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a StackOverflow y te invito a hacer el [tour], que explica como funciona el sitio. Por favor, edita la pregunta para agregar tu código, los comentarios no son para eso.  Es importante que incluyas la etiqueta del motor con el que trabajas. Yo estoy quitando varias que no vienen al caso, así que habrá espacio suficiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta siguiente se basa en los siguientes principios:

1. Determina el `estado` valiéndose de las funciones de ventana [*lag()*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) y [*lead()*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) para determinar si es el primero o último registro del mismo usuario.
2. Utiliza la [función `datefromparts()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) para *construir* una fecha en base al mes y el año

```
select   datefromparts(anio, mes, 1) Fecha
       , usuario
       , case 
           when lag(usuario) over (partition by usuario order by anio, mes) is null then 'Ingreso'
           when lead(usuario) over (partition by usuario order by anio, mes) is null then 'Retiro'
           else 'Operativo'
         end estado
  from Operaciones
 order by 2, 1
```

No solo es más eficiente por evitar uniones y la realización de `max()` y `min()`, sino por el hecho de trabajar directamente sobre los campos enteros. Tu construyes primero una cadena que luego conviertes a fecha. En un puñado de registros esa operación ni se nota, pero si tienes cierto volumen de información, el costo de dichas conversiones comienza a hacerse sentir y, para el funcionamiento de la consulta, realmente no es necesario, más que para la presentación de los datos.

Con tus datos de ejemplo, este es el resultado que devuelve:

```
Fecha      usuario estado
---------- ------- ---------
2021-01-01 A       Ingreso
2021-02-01 A       Operativo
2021-03-01 A       Operativo
2021-04-01 A       Retiro
2021-01-01 B       Ingreso
2021-02-01 B       Retiro
2021-03-01 C       Ingreso
2021-04-01 C       Operativo
2021-05-01 C       Retiro

(9 rows affected)


Completion time: 2021-05-13T10:00:15.8836046-06:00
```

Una última observación sobre una variación (que puede ser importante o no), es que cuando un usuario tiene un único registro, tu consulta lo va a mostrar *duplicado*, una vez con estado `Ingreso` y otra con estado `Retiro` (y la misma fecha), mientras que esta consulta lo va a mostrar únicamente una vez con estado `Ingreso` y ningún `Retiro`.

Supongo que ambas son incorrectas, pero dado que tu especificación no cubre el caso, lo dejé así, y queda como ejercicio para el lector definir cuál es el comportamiento que espera en ese caso y adaptar la consulta si hace falta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo... estuve revisando y resulta que la version de la base de datos es Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2... entonces algunas funciones no funcionan (datefromparts) .  .sabes alguna otra alternativa  ??

Comment: fiuuuuf... si la única incompatibilidad es esa función, puedes retornar a ensamblar la fecha como ya lo venías haciendo antes, y darle un jalón de orejas a quién siga en 2008, Microsoft ha quitado el soporte para esa versión hace ya tanto tiempo que ni recuerdo cuando fue. Tienen una bomba de tiempo allí. :)